# using random to flip coins and it whont work

Tags: python

Ok so i tried to make a program that flipped a bunch of coins by uning `random.randint(0,1)` to flip them and have it run for example 100 times (with a while loop) but it always outputed 0 as the score   help?

Code:

```
import random

i = int(1) # the thing to count how many coins have been fliped
score = int(0) #the score
coins = int(100) # the amont of coins to ble fliped

while i <= coins:
    rand = random.randrange(0,1)
    score += rand
    i += 1

print("your score is", score)
print("you flipped ", coins, " coins")
```

optuput to console (im using sublime atm  but i tried cmd too and got the same thing):

```
your score is 0
you flipped  100  coins
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: first off you dont need to do int() on a number literal it is already an int

Comment: i did it just in case a problem happned cause first i tried to make it so you could enter a number of coins you wanted to flip

Comment: Just change it to `random.randrange(0,2)`

Comment: As a side note, 1 is an `int`, so write `i = 1` instead of the useless `i = int(1)`

Answer (score 2):

From docs of `randrange` function:

> Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This
> is equivalent to choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t
> actually build a range object.

and `range`:

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the
> formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by
> the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and
> r[i] > stop.

Replace `randrange` with `randint`, and you'd get [the expected™ coin flips](https://tio.run/##TY7dCoMwDIXv@xTB3UwmQ9nd2B6mal0DtpFaJz59l/4IK5QmOel3znJ4TfYRApqFnAcn7UhGCIQ3oPXXroYLeK34ov2AJxhosx407WCkPbhFu4KWXwW9UhamGRc1inUgpwqjZUZEpJnIHwq9bU@@NMRYmgqQjfpZnTSxa@QO4fXO@lMAnxiWSTnzPT7JrunqJOcMt7yQJhi7TojFxcXqoM2VLVyrJpf1n5r8OQCwmHwbqHJR1SH8AA).

Answer (score 0):

Just like how range(0, 1) would give you all the numbers from 0 to 1 not including 1 i.e. just 0, the randrange(0, 1) function will choose numbers randomly from 0 to 1 not including 1. Try randrange(0, 2) instead.

Or even better:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
```

And the mean can be found as

```py
np.mean(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100))
```